# fclose(stdout) vs close(STDOUT_FILENO) - C

Tags: c

I want to redirect STDOUT to a file on the disk. The point is to make the printf on my program write to a file instead of the console.

I saw some articles on the web where they used:

```
dup2(fileno(outputFile), STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Or:

```
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
dup(fileno(outputFile));
```

In every tutorial they use close() and it actually works. But I was curious and I tried to use fclose(stdout) instead but some error happened when I tried to use printf:

```
fclose(STDOUT_FILENO);
dup(fileno(outputFile));
```

Error:

```
Bad file descriptor
```

My question is, why does fclose() not work but close() does?

Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to redirect stdout to a file, use a shell redirection.  If you want to learn how to redirect a file using C, you should rephrase the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`STDOUT_FILENO` is a numeric file descriptor (usually `1`). When you use `close`, you release the descriptor, but then reassign it with `dup2`.  Any output to that descriptor will now go to the new file.

`stdout` on the other hand is a `FILE*`, an object of sorts that contains a file descriptor.  Doing `printf` formats output into a buffer associated with the `FILE`, and then `write`s the buffer to the descriptor (depending upon the buffering mode).  When you `fclose` a `FILE*`, it (normally) `close`s the underlying descriptor, and frees the `FILE` object.  The `dup2` does not ressurect `stdout`, so `printf` fails.

Comment: So, how to resurrect `stdout` after this?